# tinymce django not showing up

Tags: django, tinymce, django-flatpages

I know this question have been asked here so many times, but i just cant show up Tinymce in my admin's flatpages. I don't know where I'm missing or doing something wrong. Please help me out where I'm going wrong.
The javascript file is in:

> C:\Users\Kakar\web\cms\static\js\tinymce\tinymce.min.js

urls.py:

```
    (r'^tiny_mce/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', { 'document_root': 'C:/Users/Kakar/web/cms/static/js/tinymce' }),
```

In my templates dir i have another admin folder, which have the change_form.html:
and right after {{ media }}:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
    mode: "textareas",
    theme: "simple"
    });
    </script>
```

In the firebug it says:
`ReferenceError: tinyMCE is not defined`
`tinyMCE.init({`

Please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: I noticed your url point to yoursite/tiny_mce/ but you are sourcing your script from the root of your project. It should be something like src="/tiny_mce/tinymce.min.js" this is assuming tinymce.min.js is no in a subdirectory which would then make it src="/tiny_mce/somedirectory/tinymce.js"

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but could you please elaborate more. I am new to django.

Answer (score 2):

Your url for you tinymce script is currently pointing to `http://yoursite/tiny_mce/` because of this: `(r'^tiny_mce/...` but the script you have included would attempt to GET tinymce.min.js from `http:/yoursite/tinymce.min.js` because you have not included the `/tiny_mce/tinymce.min.js` in front of it. If your tinymce.min.js is in a subdirectory you would need to include the path to it as follows `<script type="text/javascript" src="/tiny_mce/(pathtodirectory)/tinymce.min.js"></script>`